# Select multiple ranges of dataframe rows in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have a simple shiny app

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("book1"),
               uiOutput("book4"),
               uiOutput("book5")


              ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot3"),
               br(),
               rHandsontableOutput("hot5")
             )
           )))
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)
server <- function(input, output,session) {



  output$book1<-renderUI({
    numericInput("bk1", 
                 "Items in test", 
                 value = 1)
  })
  output$book4<-renderUI({
    numericInput("bk4", "From",
                 value = 1,
                 min=1,max=input$bk5)


  })
  output$book5<-renderUI({
    numericInput("bk5", "To",
                 value = 1,
                 min=1,max=input$bk1)


  })


  rt2<-reactive({
    DF=data.frame(
      Sel= rep(TRUE, as.numeric(input$bk5-input$bk4+1)),
      Id= (input$bk4:input$bk5),
      Label=paste("Item",input$bk4:input$bk5),
      Pf=as.integer(rep.int(0,as.numeric(input$bk5-input$bk4+1))),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  })
  output$hot5 <-renderRHandsontable({


    rhandsontable(rt2(),width=300,height = 300)


  }) 


}
```

As you can see I have 3 `selectInput()`. From the first I decide the number of total rows of my dataframe and I use the other 2 for the range of rows that I display. My final goal is to achieve displaying at the same time multiple ranges together. For example display rows from 1 to 5 and and then select rows from 7 to 8 and so on. Of course this could be achieved with other selectInputs but this is not practical. I was thinking if that would be possible with a `textinput()` or something that could take multiple values. I do not know if this can be done so Im open to creative ideas.
[image]